# В чем разница обычных чисел от псевдослучайных?

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Не могу понять в чем разница обычных чисел от псевдослучайных.

Можете показать на примере псевдослучайные числа и где их обычно применяют.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тип обычных и случайных чисел один и тот же - number. В типе различия нет. То есть обычное число 5 и случайное число 5 - это то же самое, просто из контекста можно додуматься, что второе случайное.

Отличие в методе их получения и назначении. С обычными числами думаю и так понятно всё. А псевдо-случайные получаются различными методами, например `Math.random()`.

Нужны случайные числа например для случайного id или класса различным элементам (как постфикс у строк), как случайный идентификатор в широком применении, для обновления кэша в URL, для отрисовки графических точек в разной позиции, для генерации шумов и так далее.

То, что числа называются псевдо-случайными, а не случайными, означает то, что они получены алгоритмом, который не совсем случайный, и который теоретически или практически можно повторить с той же последовательностью.

Comment: А каким  методом получают случайные числа?
То есть шанс получения случайного числа нельзя предсказать в отличии от псевдослучайных чисел?

Comment: @Человек с помощью специальных устройств - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB . Насчёт предсказания - шанс известен, а конкретное число предсказать нельзя.

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку источники настоящей случайности найти непросто, в программировании обычно используются *псевдослучайные* числа, полученные детерминированным алгоритмом из некоторого начального значения (англ. *seed*). В случае хорошего [генератора псевдослучайных чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) (ГПСЧ) полученная последовательность обладает теми же статистическими свойствами, что и последовательность настоящих случайных чисел. Однако никакой настоящей случайностью ГПСЧ не обладает: если взять то же самое начальное значение, на выходе получится та же самая последовательность псевдослучайных чисел.

Для примера, одним из самых простых методов генерации псевдослучайных чисел является [линейный конгруэнтный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4), в котором последующее число получается из предыдущего умножением на *a*, добавлением *c* и вычислением остатка по модулю *m*, где *a*, *c* и *m* — специальным образом подобранные константы:

```
function Random(seed) {
    var m = 0x80000000; // 2**31;
    var a = 1103515245;
    var c = 12345;
    var state = seed ? seed : Math.floor(Math.random() * (m - 1));

    // Возвращает очередное псевдослучайное число из диапазона [0,m-1]
    return function() {
        state = (a * state + c) % m;
        return state;
    }
}

// Устанавливает начальное значение
var rnd = new Random(123456789);

// Печатает 10 псевдослучайных чисел
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    console.log(rnd());
```

Псевдослучайные числа используются во многих областях, где требуются случайные числа, например, в компьютерных играх, моделировании, криптографии и т.д.

Comment: Очень интересно, но ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Различить псевдослучайное число и обычное число различить невозможно если они эквивалентны друг-другу, это можно сделать только если вы знаете как они получались, к примерам получения псевдослучайно числа см. ниже.

Ну к примеру возьмём число **1238887**(id вашего вопроса), если записывать его как обычное число то получится что-то типа такого: `Number(1238887)`, а вот в случае же псевдослучайных числен нужно получить число с помощью подобной команды: `Math.floor(Math.random()*15*100000)`(выдаёт псевдослучайно число длиной от 6 до 7 символов), тут по подробней, чтобы число не было десятичным метод `Math.random()` записывают в функцию `Math.floor()`, если подробней то функция `Math.floor()` выдаёт на отдаче ближайшее(или одинаковое) целое число данное пользователем внутри функции, а вот `Math.random()` выдаёт случайное число которое сначала умножается на **15** чтобы оно хотя бы равнялось **не** нулю, а далее умножается на **100000** чтобы его длина была минимум 6 символов, примерно так нужно сделать, чтобы получить число равное id вашего вопроса, к примерам использования случайных чисел см. ниже.

Псевдослучайные числа используются в огромном множестве сайтов, к примеру возьмём ссылку на видео с YouTube: https://yewtu.be/watch?v=1vOXUT8e8_M&nojs=1, часть символов написанная в **`v`**, то-есть: **1vOXUT8e8_M**, такие ссылки YouTube генерирует(имеется ввиду код веб-сайта который выдаёт вам результат) то или иное значение, к примеру код для создания псевдослучайного текста:

```
/*
Code licensed under GPLv3-or-later, copies should be licensed under same license.
Код находится под лицензией GPLv3-or-later(GPLv3-или-позже), копии должны быть лицензированны под той же лицензией.
*/

const chars = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890';
let result = '';
for (let i = 0, randPass; i < length; i++) {
  randPass = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
  result += chars.charAt(randPass);
}
console.log(result)
```

подобным или иным образом YouTube генерирует текст и шифрует всё это по методу шифрования [base64](https://wikiless.org/wiki/Base64) и выдаёт ссылку для видео созданного автором, также далеко за примерами ходить не надо, возьмём тот же Stackoverflow, пользователю выдаётся псевдослучайное [куки](https://wikiless.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) также *предположительно* Stackoverflow использует [base64](https://wikiless.org/wiki/Base64) для названия куки, ну или возьмём ту же огроменную горсть веб-сайтов на php с **Session ID** [куки](https://wikiless.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) которые также генерируются для пользователя.